# start with GTK3+:how to go

Tags: c++, c, gtk

I want to create a cool looking gui app in c++.i saw about gtk3+ library from gnome project.I tried this version of gtk over visual studio . gtk2+ worked but gtk3+ packge for visual studio are unstable.I want to apply css,animation and morden look over my app,which gtk2+ fail to provide.But unfortunatly gtk3+ isn't supporting visual studio so how shall i proceed...what should i do now.Also if there are other ui library capable of creating powerfull mordern ui apps(exclude microsoft WPF..bla bla..) then you can also enlist here.
Thank you